# Java: to use contains in a ArrayList full of custom object should I override equals or implement Comparable/Comparator?

Tags: java, collections, equals, comparator, comparable

I have an ArrayList full of these:

```
class TransitionState {

    Position positionA;
    Position positionB;

    int counter;

    public boolean equals (Object o){

        if (o instanceof TransitionState){

          TransitionState transitionState= (TransitionState)o;

          if ((this.positionA.equals(transitionState.positionA))
                  &&(this.positionB.equals(transitionState.positionB)))
          {
              return true;
          }
        }
     return false;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        String output = "Position A " + positionA.i+ " "+ positionA.j + " "+ positionA.orientation + " "+
                "Position B " + positionB.i + " "+ positionB.j + " "+ positionB.orientation;

        return output;
    }

}

class Position {

    int i;
    int j;
    char orientation;

    Position() {

    }


    void setIJ(int i, int j){
        this.i=i;
        this.j=j;
    }

    void setOrientation(char c){

        orientation = c;
    }

   public boolean equals(Object o){

        if(o instanceof Position){

          Position p = (Position)o;
          if((p.i==this.i)&&(p.j==this.j)&&(p.orientation==this.orientation))
          {
              return true;
          }
              else return false;

        }

            return false;
   }

} //end class Position
```

I query it with this:

```
 if(!transitionStatesArray.contains(newTransitionState)){  //if the transition state is new add and enqueue new robot positions

                 transitionStatesArray.add(newTransitionState); //marks as visited
```

I'm finding duplicate elements inside my `transitionStatesArray`, why is this?

I'm using these i,j and orientation values to fill unique values in a matrix, yet here I have a duplicate:

```
 S  .  N 
 *  *  * 
 .  D  D 


 E  .  O 
 *  *  * 
 .  D  D 


 N  .  S 
 *  *  * 
 .  D  D 


 S  .  N 
 *  *  * 
 .  D  D
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `List.contains(...)` method is defined to use `equals(Object)` to decide if the argument object is "contained" by the list.  So you need to override `equals` ... assuming that the default implementation is not what you need.

However, you need to be aware that `List.contains(...)` potentially tests the argument against every element in the list.  For a long list, that's expensive.  Depending on the details of your application, it *may be* better to use a different collection type (e.g. a `HashSet`, `TreeSet` or `LinkedHashSet`) instead of a `List`.  If you use one of those, your class will need to override `hashCode` or implement `Comparable`, or you will need to create a separate `Comparator` ... depending on what you choose.

---

(A bit more advice on the alternatives ... since the OP is interested)

The performance of `contains` on a `List` type like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` is `O(N)`. The worst-case cost of a `contains` call is directly proportional to the list length.

For a `TreeSet` the worst-case performance of `contains` is proportional to `log2(N)`.

For a `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet`, the average performance of `contains` is a constant, independent of the size of the collection, but the worst-case performance is `O(N)`.  (The worst case performance occurs if you 1) implement a poor `hashcode()` function that hashes everything to a small number of values, or 2) tweak the "load factor" parameter so that the hash table doesn't automatically resize as it grows.)

The downside of using `Set` classes are:

- they are *sets*; i.e. you cannot put two or more "equal" objects into the collection, and
- they can't be indexed; e.g. there's no `get(pos)` method, and
- some of the `Set` classes don't even preserve the insertion order.

These issues need to be considered when deciding what collection class to use.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to implement hashCode(). In general you should always do this when overriding equals anyway.

From the [collections docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html):

> This specification should not be
>   construed to imply that invoking
>   Collection.contains with a non-null
>   argument o will cause o.equals(e) to
>   be invoked for any element e.
>   Implementations are free to implement
>   optimizations whereby the equals
>   invocation is avoided, for example, by
>   first comparing the hash codes of the
>   two elements. (The Object.hashCode()
>   specification guarantees that two
>   objects with unequal hash codes cannot
>   be equal.) More generally,
>   implementations of the various
>   Collections Framework interfaces are
>   free to take advantage of the
>   specified behavior of underlying
>   Object methods wherever the
>   implementor deems it appropriate.

Comment: This assumes that the OP changes to use a different collection type.  It is not relevant if he continues using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Where does the [specification of ArrayList.contains()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) guarantee a call to equals()? It is specified by List.contains() and Collection.contains(), both of which only guarantee the result is true iff the collection contains an element e such that ( o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e) ) is true. The implementation is free to use the same hashCode shortcutting as any other collection.

Comment: @veredesmarald - here - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: As far as I can see that interface has the same contains contract as List and Collection... can you quote the specific part you are referring to? Note that requiring o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e) to be true is not the same as saying it will call equals. As noted in the summary on Collection, **Collections Framework interfaces are free to take advantage of the specified behavior of underlying Object methods [...]** In particular, we can use hashCode to short-circuit the comparison since Object guarantees o.Equals(e) must be false if o.hashCode != e.hashCode().

Comment: @veredesmarald - The javadoc for `AbstractCollection.contains` says *"This implementation iterates over the elements in the collection, checking each element in turn for equality with the specified element."*  And that's the behaviour that the `ArrayList` code implements as well ...

Comment: Checking for equality can still be implemented as `if (o.hashCode() == e.hashCode() && o.equals(e))`. Maybe that's not the way it is implemented right now, but relying on the current implementation is not a great idea. I'd rather just take the 10 seconds it takes to generate a hashCode method, and save all the headaches later on.

Comment: A general `List<E>` implementation that did that would be a mistake.  For many element classes, hashCode will (on average) be more expensive than equals.