# How to check if a string already exist in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I made this Student ArrayList that have name, age and number variable. I manually input 3 student. I want to check if a name already exist in my list. I tried to use list.contains but it seems not working. Are there certain way to do for this kind of ArrayList?

```java
public class CompareToeX {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         ArrayList<Student> obj=new ArrayList<Student>();
            obj.add(new Student("Peter", 27,1));
            obj.add(new Student("John",26,7));
            obj.add(new Student("Jack",21,5));

            if(obj.contains("Peter")){
                System.out.println("Peter on is on the list!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Peter is not on the list!");
            }
    }
}
```

This is the Student class

```java
public class Student{
    private String studentName;
    private int age;
    private int rollno;

    public Student(String studentName, int age, int rollno){
        this.studentName=studentName;
        this.age=age;
        this.rollno=rollno;
    }

    public String getStudent(){
        return studentName;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public int getRollno(){
        return rollno;
    }

     public void setStudent(String Student){
        studentName=Student;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age=age;
    }  

    public void setRollno(int rollno){
        this.rollno=rollno;
     }
}
```

After I run, the result should show that peter is on the list right. But it goes the other way around. It seems that the contains method is not working.

Comment: The problem is that your `ArrayList` doesn't contain strings, it contains `Student` objects. You need some other way to find elements in `obj`. Or a different container (like a hash-map or similar).

Comment: You cannot use `contains("Peter")` on a `List<Student>` because a `Student` is not a `String` (but rather has some `String` members, like `studentName`). You need to check for the existence of a `Student peter = new Student("Peter", 27,1);`, but a `Student` that actually `implements Comparable<Student>` preferably.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: to use contains in a ArrayList full of custom object should I override equals or implement Comparable/Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907259/java-to-use-contains-in-a-arraylist-full-of-custom-object-should-i-override-equ)

Answer (score 1):

A student isn't a name.

`.contains()` will fail here because the string `"Peter"` is not in the list. It obviously isn't; how could it be? This list only contains Student objects, not Strings, after all.

You'll have to write a for loop, or use streams.

```
boolean peterIsInTheList = false;
for (var s : students) {
    if (s.getName().equals("peter")) peterIsInTheList = true;
}
```

or

```
boolean peterIsInTheList = students.stream()
  .anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals("peter"));
```

Alternatively you could use the idea of a map; change your data structure. Instead of using a list, have a map that maps first names onto student objects:

```
Map<String, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
students.put("peter", new Student(....));

if (students.containsKey("peter")) {
  // peter is in the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the `String` `Peter` is in the list, or the list only contains `Student` object. So you can only check if `Student` is contained inside the list (be sure to implement the right `equals`/`hashcode` method if you wish to use `.contains`).

This will do

```
obj.stream()
        .filter(student -> student.getStudent().contains("Peter"))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresentOrElse(student -> System.out.println("Peter on is on the list!"), () -> System.out.println("Peter is not on the list!"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Being not a default data type, I think you need to override some functions of ArrayList first, like the .compare() one.

It was answered here too
[Java: to use contains in a ArrayList full of custom object should I override equals or implement Comparable/Comparator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907259/java-to-use-contains-in-a-arraylist-full-of-custom-object-should-i-override-equ)