# How can I avoid adding duplicated objects in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to avoid adding duplicated (student) objects in an ArrayList... I tried to loop over the array and check the ID and PhoneNO but using these two conditions I'm not able to add any object even if it's unique... Also, I tried to check using the contains() function but it's not working, it allows adding duplicated objects, how can I solve it?

```
    public void addStudent(Student newStudent) {
    //1-Looping over the ArrayList<student> and check their ID and PhoneNO (can't add any object of student)
    for(Student student:students) {
        if(newStudent.getId() == student.getId() || newStudent.getPhoneNumbre() == student.getPhoneNumbre()) {
            System.out.println("Error");
            break;
        }else
            this.students.add(newStudent);
    }
    
    //2- validate using the contains(), but it allows duplicated Objects
    if (!this.students.contains(newStudent)) 
        this.students.add(newStudent);
}
```

Comment: thats an OR operator

Comment: 1) Implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods in `Student` 2) Add them to a `Set` instead 3) Convert the `Set` to a list

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5907259/16034206 refer to this

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Student Class is missing equals() and hashCode() methods.

Implement equals() and hashCode() methods in the Student Class. You can also auto-generate the equals() and hashCode() methods if you are using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Also, instead of ArrayList, use HashSet.
HashSet will prevent insertion of duplicates because a set only contains unique objects.
If you must use ArrayList, then having the equals() is important for the contains() method of ArrayList to work properly. Also, a side note, if the two Student objects are equal then their hashCode must be the same.

Comment: Note: `hashCode()` is not needed if using `ArrayList` (but strongly recommended to override it, if `toString` is overridden)

Comment: @user16320675 – You meant that `hashCode()` should be implemented when `equals()` is overridden, and not when to `toString()` is overridden, right?

Comment: yes I meant `equals` instead of `toString`

Answer (score 0):

For two distinct object instances, the `==` operator will always return `false`, even if these two instances are equal.

In Java, the `==` operator tests for identity, not for equality (although, if two things are identical, they are obviously also equal).

The nasty thing is that in Java two apparently distinct Strings with the same contents *can* be equal *and* identical – but this depends on the underlying JVM and other conditions. Meaning, you should not rely on this!

So if `Student::getId` and `Student::getPhoneNumbre` do return object references and not Primitives, you need to compare them with `Object::equals`:

```java
if( newStudent.getId().equals( student.getId() ) 
    || newStudent.getPhoneNumbre().equals( student.getPhoneNumbre() ) ) …
```

I assume you are aware that your logic identifies a new student as a duplicate of an existing one when at least id ***or*** phone number are equals.

Otherwise, when a duplicate requires that both be equal, you should consider to implement the method `Object::equals` for the class `Student`; that would simplify the check:

```java
if( newStudent.equals( student ) ) …
```

An implementation for `equals()` may look like this:

```java
@Override
public final boolean equals( Object o )
{
  final var retValue = (this == o)
    || (o instanceof Student other
        && Objects.equals( getId(), other.getId() )
        && Objects.equals( getPhoneNumbre(), other.getPhoneNumbre() ));
  
  return retValue;
}
```

Keep in mind that it is **strongly recommended** that you *always* implement also `Object::hashCode` when you implement `Object::equals` and vice versa – even when you currently need only one of the methods!

Oh, and in your original code, you need to assure that `Student::getId` and `Student::getPhoneNumbre` will not return `null`; my suggested implementation of `equals()` does already take care of that.

---

If you are not stuck to an implementation of `List` to store the `Student` instance, you should consider to use an implementation of `Set` instead: that does the duplicate check automatically on insertion, once you provided `Student.equals()` and `Student.hashCode()`.

You can even use a `Set` implementation if duplicates are identified by either the id or the phone number, but that would be a bit nasty (although it works perfectly):

```java
Set<Student> students = new TreeSet( (s1,s2) -> Comparator.naturalOrder.compare( s1.getId(), s2.getId() ) * Comparator.naturalOrder.compare( s1.getPhoneNumbre(), s2.getPhoneNumbre() ) );
…
if( !students.add( newStudent ) ) out.println( "Duplicate!" )
```

Confessed, the output order will be strange, but this can be easily fixed …

The implementation of the `Comparator` here assumes that id and phone number will implement `Comparable`.

---

Finally, `List::contains` does not work for you because it requires that you implemented `Student::equals` properly. If you have not overridden that method, `contains()` checks for identity, not equality.

Comment: Your code in methode `equals` will not compile.

Comment: @mentallurg – Try a recent version of Java with preview enabled (although I think that pattern matching for `instanceof` will work in Java 17 without that flag).

Comment: Think of developers who have to use Java 11 or even Java 8. The problem in your answer makes your answer **not useful**. Fix the problem, and I will vote it up.

Comment: @mentallurg – Why not taking care on those that are stuck with Java 5 or even Java 1.2? Java 17 is the current LTS version, everything else is outdated and no longer relevant for someone learning Java (confessed, Java 11 has support until September 2023, but nevertheless, nobody should start a new project with it). Update your skills!

Answer (score -1):

Try using set(allows no duplicates) as given below:

```
Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();
student.add(new Student());
```

then convert the set to list, which now will have distinct student records

```
List<Student> studentList= new ArrayList<>(student);
```